# Shopware 6 Plugin - Load and display ProductStream via id

Tags: plugins, shopware6

I want to load ProductStream data via a given id and display it in the frontend, for example below the product cart.
The ProductStream is not linked to a ProductCrossSelling and therefore not linked to a product.

I loaded a ProductStream Collection via the repository.

```php
$criteria = new Criteria($producStreamIds);
$productStreamResult = $this->productStreamRepository->search($criteria, $context);
$productStreams = $productStreamResult->getEntities();
```

Now I need the associated list of products, to include them via `cms-element-product-slider.html.twig`.

I found a post with a similar question:
[How to get products from the product stream ID in Shopware 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63882913/how-to-get-products-from-the-product-stream-id-in-shopware-6)

The answer was, to use the function `loadByStream` of `Core\Content\Product\SalesChannel\CrossSelling\ProductCrossSellingRoute.php`, but this function is private.

The only public function is `load` and it needs a `$productId` as a parameter, which I do not have, because my ProductStream is not linked to a product.

Is there a clean way to load products of a ProductStream that is not linked to a ProductCrossSelling?

I have currently copied the code of the `loadByStream` function to load the products for the stream.

Or is there an other function in the shopware core that I can use for this case. I haven't found anything else.

It feels as if the current assumption is that ProductStreams are not used without connection to a ProductCrossSelling and thus to a product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A product stream is really just a collection of criterium filters. You inject `ProductStreamBuilder` and call `buildFilters` with the id of your product stream to retrieve the filters. Then you use the filters as normal with your criteria, add a limit, sorting etc and fetch your product entities.

```php
// <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\Content\ProductStream\Service\ProductStreamBuilder"/>
private ProductStreamBuilderInterface $productStreamBuilder;

// <argument type="service" id="sales_channel.product.repository"/>
private SalesChannelRepositoryInterface $productRepository;

// ..

$filters = $this->productStreamBuilder->buildFilters(
    $productStreamId,
    $salesChannelContext->getContext()
);

$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addFilter(...$filters);

$products = $this->productRepository
    ->search($criteria, $salesChannelContext)
    ->getEntities();
```